# module.export behave oddly

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

There is a surprising behaviour with `module.exports`. The following code:

```
module.exports = { test: 4};
module.exports.testMe = () => {console.log(this.test);};
```

Will output `undefined`. But:

```
module.exports.test = 4;
module.exports.testMe = () => {console.log(this.test);};
```

Will output `4`. Why does it behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason has to do with how arrow functions work, they bind to `this` (much like if you had used `.testMe = fn.bind(this);`).

In the first case, you're overwriting `module.exports`, but `this` still points to the old object. So when `testMe()` is implicitly bound to `this`, you get `undefined` because there was no `test` property on the original `module.exports`.

In the second case, you're *not* overwriting `module.exports`, so `module.exports === this` and `testMe()` is implicitly bound to `this` and outputs '4' as expected because both point to the same object, where `test` exists.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. As I understand now the `=>` as a different semantic than the `function` expression.

Comment: So it is not a good idea to use arrow for defining exported function I guess. arrow should be reserved for argument that should be a function.